# Como atualizar o valor do output em tempo real

Tags: javascript, html5, value, input-output

Olá, em uma apostila que estou lendo tem um trecho para atualizar o valor do output com base em um input type="range".
  Tem os códigos e tudo, mas apesar de estar igual(ou pelo menos parece), não consigo ver o por que de não funcionar então se possível alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Segue o código do fildset onde o input e o output estão;

```
<fieldset class="tamanhos">
    <legend>Escolha o Tamanho:</legend>
    <input type="range" min="36" max="46" step="2" name="tamanho" id="tamanho">
    <output for="tamanho" name="valortamanho" id="valortamanho">42 </output>
</fieldset>
```

Código do javascript;

```
 var inputTamanho = document.querySelector('[name=tamanho]')
 var outputTamanho = document.querySelector('[name=valortamanho]')
 /*pg 199*/
function mostraTamanho(){
    outputTamanho.value = inputTamanho.value
}

inputTamanho.oninput = mostraTamanho
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar o `oninput` diretamente na função deste modo:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var inputTamanho = document.querySelector('[name=tamanho]');
  var outputTamanho = document.querySelector('[name=valortamanho]');
  inputTamanho.oninput = function() {
    outputTamanho.value = inputTamanho.value;
    console.log(inputTamanho.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="tamanhos">
  <legend>Escolha o Tamanho:</legend>
  <input type="range" min="36" max="46" step="2" name="tamanho" id="tamanho">
  <output for="tamanho" name="valortamanho" id="valortamanho">42 </output>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, esta atualizando normalmente nesse modo.